# Can't display an image in the Thymeleaf/Spring Boot App

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have got a problem, which I have been trying to resolve for hours without any success.

I'm building a Spring Boot app with Thymeleaf. In general, I need to put a logo on the index.html page, but it doesn't display at all. I have tried different uri configurations (as in the code snippet), both with and without thymeleaf tags, none of them worked.
Other thymeleaf (eg. conditionals etc.) tags work fine - I have tested it, so dependency is not a cause.

Once, I built an app using jsp views and I didn't have any issues with images.

What do you think, am I missing something or what?

**project structure**

```
src
 |_main
      |_ java
      |_ resources
               |_ static
                      |_ images
                             |_ logo.png                    
               |_ templates
                      |_ index.html
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:replace="fragments/head"></head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light"> <!--style="background-color: blueviolet"-->
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                <img th:src="@{~/images/logo.png}">
                MyApplication
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <img th:src="@{~/static/images/logo.png}">
    <img th:src="@{~/images/logo.png}">

    <img th:src="@{//static/images/logo.png}">
    <img th:src="@{//images/logo.png}">

    <img th:src="@{/static/images/logo.png}">
    <img th:src="@{static/images/logo.png}">
    <img th:src="@{/resources/static/images/logo.png}">
    <img th:src="@{resources/static/images/logo.png}">

    <img th:src="@{//static/images/logo.png}">
    <img th:src="@{//static/images/logo.png}">
    <img th:src="@{//resources/static/images/logo.png}">
    <img th:src="@{/resources/static/images/logo.png}">

    <img th:src="@{src/main/resources/static/images/logo.png}">
    <img th:src="@{/src/main/resources/static/images/logo.png}">

    <img src="/static/images/logo.png">
    <img src="static/images/logo.png">

    <img src="/resources/static/images/logo.png">
    <img src="resources/static/images/logo.png">

    <img src="/main/resources/static/images/logo.png">
    <img src="main/resources/static/images/logo.png">

    <img src="src/main/resources/static/images/logo.png">
    <img src="/src/main/resources/static/images/logo.png">

    <img src="hotelreservation/src/main/resources/static/images/logo.png">
    <img src="/hotelreservation/src/main/resources/static/images/logo.png">

    <img src="D:/Users/Maciek/Documents/git/hotelreservation/src/main/resources/static/images/logo.png">
    <img src="D:\Users\Maciek\Documents\git\hotelreservation\src\main\resources\static\images\logo.png">

<footer th:replace="fragments/footer"></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `~`, like so:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}">
```

Also if you have Spring Security make sure to allow requests to your resources by overriding this method in your Security Configuration class (the one extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("static/**");
}
```

Comment: @J Asgarov - thank you for the suggestion, but I have tried whole bunch of different ways as in the code snippet and none of them worked (including your). Maybe I should have added some config in the Java code (I didn't write any)? I'm using Intellij IDE Ultimate version - maybe some config there?

Comment: that is weird, I use the same folder structure as you, and for me everything works. (I also use IntelliJ Ultimate, not that it matters). Do you have spring security dependency by any chance?

Comment: @J Asgarov - yes I do have Spring Security. I agree this is really weird... I also use Bootstrap, I might try without it and see what happens.

Comment: no it is not weird if you have Spring Security:) see my updated answer

Comment: @J Asgarov Thank you for your hint. It definitely helped me a lot, because I had completely different folder to be ignored in configure method (result of copying the old project ;)) however, the problem still persisted. I also had to add the following method to WebConfig class (implementing WebMvcConfigurer) to finally fix it:                                `@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }`